# MVC CDN Bundle not using local copy in debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, query-optimization, cdn

I've read a number of MVC blogs on using CDNs for hosting jQuery. They all say 
"In the code above, jQuery will be requested from the CDN while in release mode  and  the debug version of jQuery will be fetched locally in debug mode."
(e.g. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

However, When I write this code:

```
// Enable CDN support
bundles.UseCdn = true;   

//add link to jquery on the CDN
const string jqueryCdnPath = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js";
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",jqueryCdnPath)
                        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

... and debug my MVC app, the call to the google api is getting made (not my local copy as I was expecting in debug.

My build is definitely debug and in my Web.config, I have this:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

Does anyone know why the call is still being made to get jquery from the google CDN?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found the answer to this.

I have removed this line from my code.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true
```

Now when running with *debug=false* in my web.config, Bundling is enabled and the Cdn is used.

An unexpected side-effect (unexpected to me at least) of setting debug back to *debug=false* with EnableOptimizations = false is that bundling is also ignored. It would be nice to be able to keep Optimizations enabled in debug mode but to disable CDN requests. Does anyone if this is possible?